# Recursive main function analysis

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.7

Following program I saw on some webpage while studying C Language Interview questions, I want to know whether my analysis is correct or not?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void main(int j)
 {
     printf("%d\n",j);
     (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
 }
```

My analysis is that initially the argument in the main is argument count so first of all `1` will get printed on the screen, next there is a recursive conditional call to main here `(&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);` In this `&exit` is greater than `&main`, so we obtain some value here, it is multiplied with `j/1000` means until `j` is less than `1000` 
value of `(&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` will be zero, ultimately `main` function gets called so the numbers from `1,2,3,-----1000` will get printed.

Once `j` becomes `1001` the value of `(&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` will become `(&exit - &main)*1`  and the address will be `(&main + &exit - &main)(j+1);` i.e. the address of `exit` function so the program gets exit printing `1 to 1000`.

This is my analysis about this program I want to know whether my analysis about this program is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you anton there you are providing one more argument (547) with file name so argument count is 2 so the values are getting printed from 2 to 10. Is my analysis correct

Comment: This is a stupid interview question, that have to rely on implementation-specific behavior of a specific compiler, linker and runtime environment combination. Any deviation (even such things like optimizations and minor version change) will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behaviour because additive `operator -` is not defined for function pointers.

Moreover the order of functions in the resulted object file is undefined.

Also function main shall have return type int.

Comment: Oops -- that is mentioned in the comments :P

Comment: is this what you mean `When two pointers are subtracted, both must point to elements of the same array object or just one past the last element of the array object (C Standard, 6.5.6 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]); the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. Otherwise, the operation is undefined behavior`

Answer (score 0):

`j/1000` will return 1 only when `j >= 1000`

Then

```
(&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))
```

will become

```
&main + &exit - &main = &exit;
```

Until then

`main()` will be called recursively

with`(j+1)` as parameter

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same example a few days before and had spent time to understand it. I am very happy to see someone else who came across the same example if not the same webpage :)

let's analyze  the code line by line

***First LINE***

```
 void main(int j)
```

I guess if you change the line above into `void main(int argc)` you will maybe know that `j` 
will hold exactly the same value of `argc` which is `1` as no arguments will be entered while executing the program 
In fact the first parameter in `main()` function will hold always the number of arguments entered to the program including the name of the program

so if I write

```
./exeProgram // j contains 1
```

`j` will contain `1` but if you execute with an extra argument it
 will hold `2`

```
 ./exeProgram arg1 // j contains 2
```

***Second LINE***

```
 printf("%d\n",j);
```

this is a simple instruction that print the value of `j` so let's move to the third line
the most important

***Third LINE***

```
 (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
```

what the statement here is trying to do is executing the `main()` again and 
again (in a recursive way) to execute the instruction **`in a specific number of time`**

let's see the expression `&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` : 
the first term that will be executed will be `(&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` here as `j` is an integer and so `1000` so the result is always an integer but the problem is that when `j` holds a value in `1 ... 99` which is `< 1000` the return value of `j/1000` will be **`0`**

so for `j` between ***[1..99]***:

`&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` becomes  `&main + (&exit - &main)*(0)` which is 
nothing but `&main`

**

### the problem here is that substracting two pointers which don't point to the same array is considered as an undefined behavior !!

**

I will continue the analysis because the idea and the recursive approach is nice and can be used in other working situations !

so for `j=1000` now:

`&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000)` becomes  `&main + (&exit - &main)*(1)` which is `&main+&exit-&main` which is `&exit`

so let's summarize

```
if(j>=1 && j<=99)
&main(j) // will be executed when j<=99 and j>=1
else
&exit(j) // will be executed when j=1000
```

when the program reaches the `1000` value it will execute the function `exit()` and stop its execution that's it  ! :)

Please note that no need to add the `&` before the `main` or `exit`  as the function name refers always to it's address.